# How to output the date without a colon using bash command

Tags: bash, date, command

I want to output the following:

command:

> date +%T*

```
01:49:14
```

But how to display it without the colons.. any ideas? I'm using bash command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When I do `man date` I got.

> %T     time; same as %H:%M:%S

Then why don't we do which will give same output as `%T` option in `date` rather than using `%T` with external or bash tools to get results in different forms:

```
date +"%H-%M-%S"
OR
date +"%H/%M/%S"
OR
date +%H%M%S       ##Without any output delimiter
```

Comment: The dash and slash are not shell metacharacters, so they don't need to be quoted: `date +%H-%M-%S` and `date +%H/%M/%S` would work fine. But actually, I'd use `date +"%H-%M-%S"` and `date +"%H/%M/%S"`, since they match the semantics (the quoted section being the format string).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, sure thanks for letting know I have done the changes now.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score -1):

How about?

```
date +%T | sed -e "s/:/ /g"
```

Comment: IMHO, you need not to use external command to get it when `date` could do it by itself see this once too https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387878/5866580

Comment: ah, I see, it should be the better way (y)